# X Error of failed request: GLXBadRenderRequest

Tags: 16.04, python, opengl

I am using Gym AI with **mujoco** environment and trying to execute python script which keeps giving me following error.

Here’s the command I am using followed by the error:

```
$ sudo python3 main.py --env=Reacher-v1 --is_train=True --display=True
[2018-04-08 11:35:23,529] initializing glfw@(3, 1, 2)
X Error of failed request: GLXBadRenderRequest
Major opcode of failed request: 155 (GLX)
Minor opcode of failed request: 1 (X_GLXRender)
Serial number of failed request: 135
Current serial number in output stream: 136
```

Comment: You'll need to provide a lot more detail. What exactly is that Python script and what is it supposed to do?

Comment: Actually I am using reinforcement learning to make robot learn to open the door handle. But, I am able to solve this issue now and am able to run the script. Thanks for your response.

Comment: If you solved your problem yourself, please [answer your own question](/help/self-answer) and accept your answer. Don’t put the answer in your question or the comments! :-)

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*  
sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-video-intel libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-dri xserver-xorg-core  
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg 
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
```